# How to use recaptcha v3?

Tags: android, recaptcha

I already use recaptcha v2 in my app. now I found there is a recaptcha v3 version. But can't get an option to implement that in android app.

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(YOUR_API_SITE_KEY)
            .addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this,
                new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response) {
                        // Indicates communication with reCAPTCHA service was
                        // successful.
                        String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
                        if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
                            // Validate the user response token using the
                            // reCAPTCHA siteverify API.
                        }
                    }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener((Executor) this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                            // An error occurred when communicating with the
                            // reCAPTCHA service. Refer to the status code to
                            // handle the error appropriately.
                            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                            int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + CommonStatusCodes
                                    .getStatusCodeString(statusCode));
                        } else {
                            // A different, unknown type of error occurred.
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: still, don't find any solution